# Conditional based linking of a "GridHyperLinkColumn" in javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview

I need to do conditional linking in a grid hyperlink column. In the grid, there is a column whose value is populating from the 'URL' column in SQL table bound with the grid. In the JS, I have made the hyperlink column as below:

```
<sq8:GridHyperLinkColumn  DataNavigateUrlFields="URL" Target="_blank" AllowFiltering="false" DataTextField="URL"  DataTextFormatString="{0}" AllowSorting="False" HeaderText="SKU's List" SortExpression="URL" UniqueName="URL" FilterControlAltText="">
       
<HeaderStyle Wrap="true" Width="300px" />
<ItemStyle CssClass="EligibleSku" Wrap="true" Width="500px"></ItemStyle>      
</sq8:GridHyperLinkColumn>
```

However, the value in URL column in Sql table can have two types of values, it can be either starting from "https:" or can simply contain plain text instead of a link.
I want that when URL has a valid link type data, then the hyperlink grid column has value as a link and when it URL column in sql table contains only a text then the grid column should display as plain text instead of link.

Please suggest how to do this. Thanks.